# Error while installing request module

Tags: node.js, http, request, fs

I want to install request module in node.js, but whenever i try installing using npm, it throws several error in my command prompt.

```
npm install request
```

When i try to install , it throws some related to proxy error, can anybody help me to sort it out.
Errors are :
[image: Error after trying to install any module]

Comment: you should add system parameters such as OS, versions of envorinment software etc...

Comment: add in the sense like, u want OS details?

Comment: You don't give any details on what versions of packages you have installed! Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: okay sorry for that, because i am newbie in this field and you can easily get that by seeing my profile reputations. 
As mentioned in the image, i'm using node version **v4.2.2** and npm version **v2.14.7**. As i am doing all these stuff using my corporate network, will that be a issue ?

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have a problem with connection proxy, so try to install it manually download request package there:  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests
  After on the folder execute python setup.py install :)